# Can a composite format in String.Format() be used to return a substring?

Tags: substring, string.format

I apologize for what seems to be an exceedingly simple question, but after 4 hours of searching and beating my head against the wall, I'm doubting my sanity.

I need a string format expression that trims a supplied string argument much like Substring(0,1). Although I've never seen this in code, it just seems like it should be possible.

Here's a very basic example of what I'm trying to do:

```
string ClassCode = "B608H2014"; // sample value from the user's class schedule
string fRoom = "{0:0,2}"; 
string fGrade = "{0:2,2}";
string fYear = "{0:5,4}"; 

string Classroom = String.Format(fRoom, ClassCode); // intended result - "B6" 
string Gradelevel = String.Format(fGrade, ClassCode); // intended result - "08" 
string Schoolyear = String.Format(fYear, ClassCode); // intended result - "2014"
```

This is a very basic example, but I'm trying to use the String.Format() so I can store the format pattern(s) in the database for each respective DTO property since the class code layouts are not consistent. I can just pass in the formats from the database along with the required properties and it extracts what I need.

Does this make sense?

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but if you just want to extract defined portions of strings, why not store in the database the start position and length and use .Substring?

Comment: Not all of the properties are strings. This just happens to be the only part of it that's giving me trouble. The other portions such as tuitions, financial aid, semester start and end dates, graduation dates, etc. are all apart of it, but I already have the String.Format() handling all of the other formats. So my process can't be changed at this point without going back to the client and making major changes.

Comment: Ok, I got it all resolved. Natively, String.Format() cannot truncate or trim the string, but I was able to create my own custom formatter and call that instead that handled the process perfectly.